# Linker errors when linking a built libevent as a static library, but works when linking as a shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, static-libraries, libevent

I've built the libevent library from source as static library using GCC compiler(on linux).
Cmake options:

```
cmake -B build -S . -DEVENT__DISABLE_OPENSSL=ON -DEVENT__LIBRARY_TYPE=STATIC -DEVENT__DISABLE_DEBUG_MODE=ON  
cmake --build build --config Release
```

Linking library in CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}

        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libevent_core.a

        )
```

But I am still getting errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/libevent_test/main.cpp:65: undefined reference to `event_base_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/libevent_test/main.cpp:85: undefined reference to `event_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/libevent_test/main.cpp:89: undefined reference to `event_add'
```

Also I tried to build libevent as shared library (.so output file) and it linked well.
In CMakeLists.txt I just changed `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libevent_core.a` to             `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libevent_core.so`.
And my program compiled ok. Why static library doesn't links?
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libevent_core.a` library you need to link with the libraries it depends from. Unlike to **shared** library, a **static** one doesn't contain list of its dependencies.

Comment: Use `nm` to list the symbols defined in the libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I tried to link libevent.a, libevent_core.a, libevent_extra.a and libevent_pthreads.a. No result.
@stark, I checked all my static libs, actually, no one of them contain `event_new` function. It's weird. But contain `event_add` which is undefined reference too. I can post list of symbols in libraries. Do?

Comment: @stark, I make a mistake, `event_new` is there in libevent_core.a too. All functions which is undefined reference is defined in libraries.

Comment: I've taken a short look at the `CMakeLists.txt` file and it looks like the file provides `install`/`export`,so you should be able to install the lib to a directory of your choice: `cmake -B build -S . ... -D CMAKE_PREFIX=<path to install to>` and after the lib is built `cmake --install build` In that case you should be able to use `find_package(LIBEVENT libevent REQUIRED PATHS <path to ...config.cmake> NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH NO_CMAKE_PATH NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH)` to locate the package;the path depends on where exactly libevent places the import script(named `libevent-config.cmake` or similar)

Comment: Also I recommend avoiding the use of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. This makes it harder to reuse the project as part of a larger project. (If you use `add_subdirectory` to "include" the dir containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file). Instead use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to refer to the directory containing the current `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used `target_link_libraries` for executable, but libevent was used in static library which is linking to executable.
Now I link libevent directly to static library which is using it. And it works.